# opening links in separate tabs

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

this line of code works when trying to open a link in a separate tab: `clickonlinkTab = Keys.chord(Keys.COMMAND, Keys.ENTER)`

but manually when pressing command and enter with the cursor on a link does not open the link. why does this only work with selenium webdriver?

Comment: Because it's in unsuitable state.Then you put the cursor on a link its state is :hover. But you need :active state.  Just try to go to a link by Tab or you can use Force state for a link element in Chrome Developer Tools

Comment: but why does the code work using selenium? does selenium converts the state to active by default?

Comment: It's interesting, yes. I've discovered that sendKeys contains scrollIntoView calling within. Mb scrollIntoView changes an element state to focus and that's why it works